# How to show "33 minutes ago" on Grafana dashboard with InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have recently set up Grafana with InfluxDB. I'd like to show a panel that indicates how long it has been since an event took place.

Examples:

- Server last reported in: 33 minutes ago
- Last user sign up: 17 minutes ago

I can get a single metric pretty easily with the following code:

`SELECT time, last("duration") as last_duration FROM custom_events ORDER BY time DESC`

But I can't seem to get Grafana to do what I want with the time field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is grafana showing? Nothing? Or is the time just improperly rounded?

Comment: @beckettsean Grafana just shows the metric "last_duration", but not the time.

Comment: So on the Y axis is the last_duration, isn't the X axis the timestamp?

Comment: @beckettsean Grafana will not allow me to use the timestamp or a tag as a value. It will only allow me to use an InfluxDB field as a value.

Comment: @beckettsean There are no X- and Y-axis on a Grafana table or singlestat panel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Grafana(4.6.0) this is now possible with singlestat panels.

1. GoTo the `Options`-Tab
2. Select `Value` -> `Stat` -> `Time of last point`
3. Select `Value` -> `Stat` -> `Unit` -> `Date & time` -> `From Now`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its currently(4.0.3) not possible to show the last timestamp in singlestat panels. But there is an [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6710) for supporting this. Hopefully we will find time to implement this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In 8.4.0 There is a unit selection that allows you to do this, make sure your timestamp is in milliseconds since the epoch and select `From Now` as the unit in the dropdown menu

[singlestat pannel expressing time since](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YW3R.png)