# InfluxDB - Query milliseconds since last data point in a time series

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is it possible to write a InfluxDB query that will give me the number of milliseconds since the last entry in a time series? I'd like to add a single-stat panel in Grafana displaying how old the data is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible since you are not able to query the time alone. A influxdb query needs at least **one non-time** field in a query. You could workaround that by double saving the time in a extra field which you are able to query alone.

But you still want to use `now() - "the extra time field"`. But as far as I found out you also can't use `now()` inside grafana.

**Update**: there is a [Feature-Request] now on grafanas github. Make sure to vote it up so it gets implemented one day: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6710

**Update 2**: The feature got finaly implemented -> See my answer here: [How to show "33 minutes ago" on Grafana dashboard with InfluxDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640978/how-to-show-33-minutes-ago-on-grafana-dashboard-with-influxdb/49321045#49321045)

Comment: `select now() - "the extra field" from ...` is an invalid InfluxDB query, giving the error `error parsing query: binary expressions cannot mix aggregates and raw fields`. So currently this is not possible with InfluxDB.